# Import Data into Cassandra from MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, cassandra

I am completely new to Cassandra and I need to import a massive amount of data from MS SQL Server into Cassandra. I cannot seem to find a demo on how to import into Cassandra using through datastax c# driver or using Cassandra's bulk loader (sstableloader).
Any help will be extremely appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Will you be importing CSV dumps of the relational tables? The reason there is not a good demo on how to perform an export/import for a relational model is thanks to a major shift in data model design. You are taking data that is formed into rigid schemas and hopefully normalized and trying to push it into partitions that should be designed for queries. The [COPY](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) command is how you could load a csv file into Cassandra.

Comment: I would rather be importing from .dat files. As I have a whole lot of lines, with bcp.exe it will be faster to create the .dat files with the data. Will it be the same functionality as with CSV files? And also, I saw that on Windows I might get errors in trying to import into Cassandra. Is there a way I could do it from C# code? Even with CSV files?

Comment: You can format the .dat file so it can be ingested through the COPY command. That will not be as simple as just running `COPY`. You could write a C# program to process each line in your file as an insert statement in CQL but I would not be much help in getting that set up.